# How to get the Keyword object from Component CustomMeta?

Tags: 2011, broker

We have a component with a certain keyword field, which is located at the metadata tab.

Using the Broker API we would like retrieve the keyword for a certain component. The custom_meta is returning the keyword title. We can't use the taxonomy api to get the keyword object based on the keyword title. If we use the API for querying the item_categories_and_keywords table, the API is only returning the ITEM_REFERENCE_ID. We don't need this ID, because this is the ID of the component which we already have.

So my question: is there a way to use the broker.querying API to get the result rows, instead of getting a list with string values containing the item_reference_id?

In the API there is information about query.getQueryResult() but the method is protected, so we can't use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Content Delivery API to retrieve keywords for given category](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/463/using-content-delivery-api-to-retrieve-keywords-for-given-category)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate - Mirjam is trying to NOT use taxonomies (as far as I can tell)

Comment: Are you trying to get the com.tridion.taxonomies.Keyword object from the CustomMeta field or a list of related Keywords by a given Keyword title? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Seems like we're looking for the custom meta for a given item, which I think Bart covers in [this answer on the CD API](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/2783/46).

Comment: I am trying to get the com.tridion.taxonomies.Keyword object from the CustomMeta field. But the custom meta field is only returning the title.

Comment: It is not duplicate. We just want to get the keyword object of a certain component. The search API is only returning the keyword title. We need the keyword object.

Comment: We have a component with item_id 1109113
The component has a metadatafield 'process-type', this metadatafield is a category field of the category 'VIB Procestype' 

If you use sql you can get the taxonomy_id and keyword_id by running the simple query:

select * from item_categories_and_keywords where item_reference_id = 1109113 and category = 'VIB Procestype'

But we do wanna use the API, to get this result. Is this possible? Because the search query is not returning a row, but it is returning the item_reference_id which refers to the component.

Comment: Seems like the API is build on the idea of "getting componentids based on keywords", we would like to "get keywords based on componentids"

Answer (score 2):

First of all - interesting problem. I never had to get the `Keyword` itself before, so I'm very curious why you need it. I would appreciate if you gave more details about what you are trying to accomplish.

I couldn't find a simple straight forward solution (and by that I mean a one or two lines Broker API call to read the `Keyword`). Instead I came up with the helper method below (Java code):

```
public Keyword getKeyword(ComponentMeta meta, String fieldName) {
    CustomMeta custom = meta.getCustomMeta();
    Map<String, NameValuePair> map = custom.getNameValues();
    NameValuePair pair = map.get(fieldName);
    String value = (String) pair.getFirstValue();

    Category[] categories = meta.getCategories();
    for (Category category : categories) {
        for (Keyword keyword : category.getKeywordList()) {
            if (keyword.getKeywordName().equals(value)) {
                return keyword;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Obviously there are plenty of checks missing from the code-above, but I hope the idea is clear: that is, we read the `CustomMeta` first and get the String value of the Keyword metadata field. Then we match this value to all keywords available under the getCategories() method. This is a list of Category object that the current ComponentMeta is tagged against. One word of caution here: since we are talking about several Categories, there might be the risk of a Keyword title clash (i.e. there might be more Keywords with the same title, since they belong to different Categories). So you would be better off passing in a parameter with the Category name, such that you don't need to iterate over all Categories.

You would use the sample above in the following manner:

```
// get somehow a ComponentMeta object
ComponentMetaFactory factory = new ComponentMetaFactory(PUBLICATION_ID);
ComponentMeta meta = factory.getMeta(COMPONENT_ID);

// call the helper method
Keyword keyword = getKeyword(meta, "process-type");
```